# Remove any charachter If not sandwiched between special strings in notepad++

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I'm trying to remove all characters except those sandwiched between 2 strings,

my original text:

```
BlahBlahBlahBlahBlahbeginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,1endblahblahblahblblah
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXbeginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,2endblahb2XXXXXXXXXXXX
YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYbeginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,3endYYYYYYYYYYYY
UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUbeginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,4endUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV
```

The desire output:

```
beginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,1end
beginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,2end
beginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,3end
beginningMY,IMPORTANT,text,4end
```

I used this

```
beginning(.*)end
```

RegEx in regexr.com and got a useful list like this

[image]

I'm not allowed to upload my data to any website so how can I do this On Notepad++ ?

[image]

Comment: `(beginning.*end)|.` => `(?{1}$1\n:)`

Comment: Another idea: Search for [`(?s).*?(beginning.*?end)|.+` and replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/Uh2KAW/1)

Comment: Further have a look at [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) which is useful for skipping certain parts but match others. It is often used in combination with variations of [the trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). For your input e.g. search for [`beginning.*?end(*SKIP)(*F)|.` and replace with empty](https://regex101.com/r/H9CJ4M/1).